# GIF image loading slow issue

Tags: android, gridview, loading, android-glide, fresco

I am working with an android application, where i have number of urls of gif image. I need to show these gifs in a GridView. I have used Glide, Fresco etc. third party libs to load gifs, but still it talking lot of time to load gifs into the gridview. My requirement is to show thumbnail/preview of image first, while talking time to download and then start playing animation after the download complete. Is there any efficient solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you own the backend from where the GIF are downloaded. I suggest you to create low res images of this GIFs (tooking the first frame of the GIF for example).
When the user enter the GridView, you fast download the low resolution thumbnails, then in parallel you start downloading the real GIF and substitute them one to one when the single download is completed.

If you don't own the backend and the content owner doesn't provide a thumbnail download system, you can't do anything :(

Comment: Yes! i don't have my own backend to manage the GIFs. I have GIFs with 6-8 MB of size each. I don't know how the facebook android app process gifs, if i posted the same gif's url with same size. Facebook app quite great to process the gif, it show the preview first and when user clicks it then play animation.

Comment: But that it's because they own the backend and can perform all the optimizations needed :D (surely in a more performant way than what i think). PS: Be sure that Facebook doesn't have 6-8MB GIF's to download

Comment: May be your right, but i don't think so all the processing has done on backend side, there may be some algorithm implemented on client side. for example www.gif-vif.com, this website having the gifs of larger size, but the website shows the gifs quite smoothly. They have the android application as well, and the same smoothness is there.

Comment: You can inspect the network traffic in the site using the browser console, to see in which way they handle this thing

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an application that normally shows 4 or 5 simple GIFs (size limited to 500KB) I use Glide in a separated thread. The thread first extract bitmaps and later it create an array of resized to view dimensions Drawables, it also creates an array of delays between frames and at the end the thread calls postInvalidate(), nothing are drawn until thread terminates but later due I have the frames saved all is redrawn very fast. I use a Runnable with postDelayed to change frames.

Comment: But i have GIFs in hundreds to thousands with size of 6-8 MB, anyways thanks for replying.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion @Tonteria24, can you help me with some code or example for the same for more clarification.

Comment: As I said my app was designed for display 4 or 5 small GIFs that are preloaded in memory, it will never work for hundreds of 6-8 MB GIFs it will raise an Out of Memory exception